# Protractor - Cucumber config query

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

My query is how config.js will be called when we say for example.. "npm run test" this will run tests as per the configuration defined in config.js

example my package.json contains

```
"scripts" : {
"test" : "Env=ST CukeTags=regression testrunner -s functional"
}
```

another query I had is, where can I find the details about how these config files, hooks file will be interrelated? how will these be called during the protractor tests running?

Comment: Please give more detail about `testrunner`,  It comes from a npm package or other ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the test script in your package.json

That test script will tell the command to run protractor giving the path of config file.

```
 "scripts":{"test": "protractor typeScript/config/config.js"}
```

Here the test command will run protractor with the config file inside typescript/config folder.

Sample config file for protractor and cucumber

```
    import * as path from "path";
import { browser, Config } from "protractor";
import { Reporter } from "../support/reporter";
const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";

export const config: Config = {

    seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",

    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

    baseUrl: "https://www.google.com",

    capabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
    },

    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

    specs: [
        "../../features/*.feature",
    ],

    onPrepare: () => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
    },

    cucumberOpts: {
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
        format: "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
        require: ["../../typeScript/stepdefinitions/*.js", "../../typeScript/support/*.js"],
        strict: true,
        tags: "@CucumberScenario or @ProtractorScenario or @TypeScriptScenario or @OutlineScenario",
    },

    onComplete: () => {
        Reporter.createHTMLReport();
    },
};
```